# Django: how to use two different databases with Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, wagtail

Inside a Django project, I have one app, otherapp, which hits a Postgres database on a remote server that contains scraped data. I have a second app, content, which hits a *different* Postgres database on the *same* remote server, and contains pages I'd like to have served through the Wagtail CMS.

I installed Wagtail locally using [these](http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/v1.3.1/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html) instructions (I did not use the Wagtail installer). I got it working locally. Then, I did a pg_dump of the local database and did psql db2 < db2dumpfile.sql on the remote database server.

Each of the apps works fine locally in isolation, but I can't get them to work together. I thought I could use a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/) to specify which database I want used to retrieve different types of data.

But, when I put the database router into the settings file, it starts to fail. How can I fix this? Do I need to declare wagtailcore somewhere else in the project?

**settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'USER': DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT 
    },
    'CMS': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db2',
        'USER': DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT 
    }

}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [ 'projectname.routers.FindRouter',]
```

**routers.py:**

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
import socket
class FindRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints) :
        if model._meta.app_label == 'content' :
            return 'CMS'
        return None
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'content' :
            return 'CMS'
        return None
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'content' :
            return 'CMS'
        return None
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'content' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'content':
            return True
        return None
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'content' :
            return db == 'CMS'
        return None
```

This is the error I am getting when I do runserver:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cms/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wagtail.wagtailforms',
 'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
 'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
 'wagtail.wagtailsites',
 'wagtail.wagtailusers',
 'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
 'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
 'wagtail.wagtailimages',
 'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
 'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
 'wagtail.wagtailcore',
 'modelcluster',
 'compressor',
 'taggit',
 'otherapp',
 'content']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  123.                 response = middleware_method(request)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/middleware.py" in process_request
  11.             request.site = Site.find_for_request(request)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py" in find_for_request
  122.                 return Site.objects.get(hostname=hostname)  # Site.DoesNotExist here goes to the final except clause

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  381.         num = len(clone)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  240.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1074.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  52.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  852.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /cms/
Exception Value: relation "wagtailcore_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ge_id", "wagtailcore_site"."is_default_site" FROM "wagtailco...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Have you tried migrating your CMS db? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases

Comment: If you're trying to serve wagtail out of the CMS database, you probably need to set up your router to handle all of the wagtail applications as well.

Comment: I did migrate. A new error arose: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Joey Wilhelm is correct - Wagtail frequently performs SQL joins between tables from Wagtail's own apps and your own page models, so those will absolutely, definitely need to be in the same database.

Comment: gasman: But would this split be feasible at all? Or does Wagtail do joins across to e.g. the user table?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up and put the Wagtail tables back into the first database, and now the two parts of the application are working together fine.